# configure new linked server from SQL Server 2016 to Oracle 12c

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2016, oracle-12c, linked-server

I'm having difficulty creating a Linked Server in SQL Server 2016 to talk to a remote Oracle database.

I have installed Oracle Database Client 12c. First I installed InstantClient and then later realizing I needed more functionality installed Runtime. During the setup I accepted `C:\Oracle\product\12.1.0\client_1` as the Oracle home directory. For the Oracle Home User, I used the Windows Built-in Account `NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE`.

I used Oracle Net Configuration Assistant to create a tnsnames.ora file with alias = `MyAlias` and service name = `MyServiceName`. Net Configuration Assistant was able to test the database connection successfully after I provided credentials for the remote database.

The tnsnames.ora file created by Oracle Net Configuration Assistant was in this folder: `C:\Oracle\product\12.1.0\client_1\network\admin`

From a Powershell prompt, I ran `tnsping MyAlias` and got `OK (200 msec)`.

I think (hope!) this means I got the Oracle side correct.

On the Microsoft side, I installed .NET Framework 3.5. Then I downloaded and installed Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) from [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html). Specifically I downloaded **ODAC122010Xcopy_x64.zip** and followed the instructions in the readme file included. The command line options I used during install were:

```
 .\install.bat all c:\oracle odac true true
```

The parameters of the above commmand were:

- **component_name** = `all` (install all Oracle Providers)
- **oracle_home_path** = `c:\oracle` (should it be the Oracle base or the subfolder?)
- **oracle_home_name** = `odac` (determines registry key path)
- **install_dependents** = `true`
- **machine_wide_configuration** = `true` (this parameter was a guess; I want this to work for all users of this machine)

I then added C:\oracle and C:\oracle\bin to the beginning of the Environment variable PATH. In Powershell this was:

```
 [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path","C:\oracle;C:\oracle\bin;" + $env:Path, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```

Within SQL Server Management Studio, I can see OraOLEDB.Oracle in the list of Linked Server Providers.

Now trying to create the Linked Server. Here's my config:

[image: screenshot of SSMS Linked Server wizard]

For security, I'm trying for now with a fixed security context, using the same credentials that worked when testing the connection with Oracle Net Configuration Assistant.

It doesn't work. Here's the generic error:

> The linked server has been created but failed a connection test. Do
>   you want to keep the linked server?
>
> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider
>   "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "MYLINKEDSERVER". OLE DB provider
>   "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "MYLINKEDSERVER" returned message
>   "ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified".
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7303)

What am I missing? What diagnostic tests would be valuable?

Comment: Could you post the location of the tns.names file which contains your service? ODAC probably uses different tns.names file.

Comment: Question has been updated w/ path of the automatically created `tnsnames.ora` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your Data Source and Provider String to MYALIAS.  Looking at the three Oracle Linked Servers I have on my server, that is how I have them setup.[image]

Comment: It turns out that Product Name doesn't have any effect. It can be "Oracle" or "asdfasdf". Provider string can remain blank. The real fix was **Data source** has to be `MyAlias`.

Comment: @dlh - well, to be more accurate, the real fix was Data source has to be the name of a net service name in your tnsnames.ora file.  Not necessarily "MyAlias".  Your root problem, as identified by the ORA-12154 in your error stack, was the value of Data source was not found as a net service name in tnsnames.ora.

Comment: Hi all , How to set the role with "SYSDBA" into the "Linked server"

Answer (score 0):

I checked it today on my MS SQL 2016 and oracle 12c and in works fine.

You don't need oracle instant client - only oracle ole db provider and `tnsnames.ora`

you have to `set "TNS_ADMIN=C:\oracle\network\admin"` and `"ORA_CLIENT_PATH=C:\oracle"
and add "c:\oracle;c:\oracle\bin"` to PATH

in the "Linked Server" Setting you have to fill "dataSource" with the alias from `tnsname.ora`. "productName" can be empty

rolf

Answer (score -2):

at the command prompt (`cmd`) type

```
tnsping dbname
```

The description string you get is the connect information. The script below should create the basic connect information for a linked server to Oracle in SQL Server management studio.

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'ORCL12C', @srvproduct=N'Oracle', @provider=N'OraOLEDB.Oracle', @datasrc=N'Orcl12c', @provstr=N'((DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ORCL12C)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = orcl12c)));'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'ORCL12C',@useself=N'True',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=NULL,@rmtpassword=NULL
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'ORCL12C',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=N'HOME2\hughsm',@rmtuser=N'NORTHWIND',@rmtpassword=N'password'
```

Comment: that did not work for me, starting with `tnsping`